# Trying to install MediaWiki, getting error: "Tables creation failed. Make sure user can write to schema."

Tags: heroku, mediawiki, heroku-postgres

I'm getting the following error when attempting to run the MediaWiki installation, hosted on Heroku, and configured to connect to a Heroku Postgres database:

> Tables creation failed. Make sure that the user "xyz" can write to the schema ""

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution - just needed to put a value into the **Schema** field on the 'Database Connection' wizard page. Any short string value should do; I used: `mediawiki`.

Comment: Similarly when using the CLI `maintenance/install.php` script I had to pass a string to the `--dbschema` option, which incidentally doesn't appear as an option when running the script with `--help`!